# Has anyone thrown a punch in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I was reading through [this article](https://www.theforce.net/fanfilms/production/clements_tutorial/index.asp) on the choreography of lightsaber fights in Star Wars fan films, when the following section prompted me to wonder if any of the Star Wars movies showed someone punching somebody else?

> 5. **Don’t Stop When You Get in Close** – ...when two fighters are locked face to face, weapons crossed, that’s not where fighters stop to push and talk, but precisely where they immediately act to instantly employ a grappling or disarming technique that results in a killing move! ... if you find yourself close enough to just reach out and **punch your opponent in the face** with your hand, well, you are also close enough to do far worse with your weapon.

Upon searching for an answer, I found [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1j6O7UR0YM) where Lando gets punched in one of the animated series (though admittedly not during a fight or in the face), and that there's something called a [Force Punch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_punch) which isn't a real punch by my count. I certainly can't think of any straight out fist fights from the films, but maybe amidst the lightsaber swings and blaster shots someone felt like bruising their knuckles on someone's cheek.

Comment: I want to say this happens in one of the young Obi-Wan fights, against Maul or maybe Anakin? I will try to find it and provide an actual source.

Comment: i think obi-wan gets elbowed? there are definitely some kicks in the new trilogy.

Comment: @Himarm:   You mean the one that isn't even out?  (jk)

Comment: @ThePopMachine those arnt the new trilogy yet since they havnt even come out!.

Comment: "Punch. Or punch not. There is no throw." — [Dumbledore](https://killbill.fandom.com/wiki/Bill?file=BillPromo.jpg)

Comment: ***Punch it, Chewie***

Comment: Grievous kicks and punches Kenobi pretty hard shortly before getting killed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens in the fight between Qui-Gon, Obi-Wan, and Darth Maul in Episode 1: The Phantom Menace. The fight can be found here:

Maul lands a number of kicks throughout the fight, especially early, but around 1:05 you can see Qui-Gon backhand Darth Maul off of a ledge while engaged in a lightsaber duel.

Comment: It's not part of a lightsaber duel, but there is a scene in TESB where Han punches Lando in the face, immediately before Han is dragged away to be tortured: "You're a real hero, aren't you? My old *friend*." **(punch)**

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Han also engages in hand to hand on Endor in RotJ. The group stumble upon a few scout troopers and Han wrestles him to the ground.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes.** Han Solo punched Lando in the face in *Empire Strikes Back*.

Also, In Legends, Vader punches a guy a couple times.

Also I think punches are thrown in *The Mandalorian* TV Series. There are other examples that I have missed out.

Comment: I've added a poor quality YouTube clip of the scene, best I could find. Please try and include the evidence in the answer yourself like you have done with the Vader comic, though that would be better if you included the comic panels (and comic name) instead of the video!

Comment: also, Lando fakes a punch at Han when he [Han] arrives at Cloud City

Comment: And then Chewie throttles Lando for a good five minutes before they leave.

Answer (score 0):

Spoilers below.

> Not from the movies, but there are a plethora of punches on Republic Commando series. One recieved by Kal Skirata, while performing the traditional Mandalorian war ritual / dance, thrown by Ordo (this punch can pass unmarked as unintentional). Another one was received by a to-be Imperial ensign, thrown by, if I recall, Null commando Mereel. Another one, received by ARC trooper Maze, second in command of Arligan Zey, thrown by Ordo. Another one received by a deserted clone trooper (could be Spar), thrown by Darman. Another one, or rather quite a beating if you will, received by Kal Skirata again, performed by Darman.
>
> I can't recall but Tahiri, while she was the apprentice of Darth Caedus, could have received a punch from Mirta Gev. She was sure to have received an unconsciousness from the same woman, however, if by other means.

I could quote but I don't have access to my library right now unfortunately.

Tip of the day: Try not to upset Mandalorians.